# How to Update DynamoDB Table from Hive

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, sql-update, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a external Hive table that is connected to a DynamoDB, and thus I can insert data into DynamoDB table from Hive.  But now, I want to be able to update the table.  I tried to enable transaction on the Hive table, so that I can use update command on the Hive table.  But I get the error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:The table must be bucketed and stored using an ACID compliant format (such as ORC))
```

So, my question is how can I update DynamoDB table from Hive?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the following at the top of your hive script:

```
SET hive.txn.manager = org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DbTxnManager;
SET hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
```

And probably also concurrency:

```
SET hive.support.concurrency = true;
```

And the docs seem to indicate updated dynamodb is quite simple:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMRforDynamoDB.Tutorial.CopyDataToDDB.html